# Validate User Information on Registration Page

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, onblur

I want to create a registration page for my web site.

I have three Text Boxes, one for user name, another for password and third for repeat password.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
<asp:TextBox ID="PassWord" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
<asp:TextBox ID="RE-Pass" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Now I want to check these three Text Box's values.

For the first Text Box, I should check it's value by connecting to a database to check it's unique. For the two other text boxes, I should check their values are the same.

I used on blur event but it is a client side (javascript) event not a server side event.

How can I check these value using on blur event or any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [ASP.net validator controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwd43d0x%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

For the password textboxes, use the CompareValidator control.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Compares the value entered by the user in an input control with the
>   value entered in another input control, or with a constant value.

You'd need something along the lines of:

```
<asp:textbox ID="Textbox1" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:textbox>
<asp:textbox ID="Textbox2" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:textbox>
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="No Match." ControlToValidate="Textbox1" ControlToCompare="Textbox2"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

For the username textbox you could use a Custom Validator control.

You'll need something along the lines of:

**ASPX Page**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid User     Name" ControlToValidate="TextBox3" 
OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
     bool userNameIsValid = true; // Database check here.

     if (userNameIsValid)
         args.IsValid = true
     else  
         args.IsValid = false;
   }
```

Here's a [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5z00s5e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on MSDN which describes using this control to validate user input against a database.

Comment: when I use customValidator , the page relaods. how can I prevent it?

Comment: @Saman Try placing your controls in an [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a trivial task. Obviously you should make the checks on the server side. You could make [ajax calls](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) on the `onblur` handling. You could use [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to do it.

Hope I helped!